# RxJS Function Signature

Tags: javascript, rxjs, rxjs5

https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/mergemap.html

I am learning RxJS and find the documentation in below format.

```
mergeMap(project: function: Observable, resultSelector: function: any, concurrent: number): Observable
```

I understand `concurrent: number` which means the third argument and its of type number. However, I don't understand first argument `project: function: Observable`. Is there some naming convention on the usage of 2 colons?

Answer (score 1):

It means

`project` returns a function of type `Observable`

`resultSelector` returns a function of type `any`